# how to use void pointer as function return type In C

Tags: c, function, void-pointers

So I am planing to Write a function to return a random array element. The function accept two
parameters—an array of void pointers and the array length. It should return a void pointer.
The idea is to take the given array, which comes in the form of an array of void pointer, the function will return an random element of the the array.
The question I have is, what do I need to do to return a pointer, what do I need to do to the "result" so I can return it like that? After wards what do I need to do to access it again?
Thanks

Here is what I have done, but I'm getting the:

```
 "25: error: invalid use of void expression"
```

with warnings like:

```
" warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic"
```

My code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
void *randomNum(void * array, int length)
{
    void * result;  
    result=array[rand()%(length-1)];
    return result;
}    
int main()
{
int i;
srand(13);
int array[9]={1,5,6,85,132,65463,1354,5863,134};

for (i=0;i<9; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",*randomNum(array,9));
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid void pointers. Having types enables the compiler to provide checks for you

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to return the `int`s inside the array converted to `void*` or do you what to return the address of that array element?

Comment: Why is somebody voting up a confused question like this?

Comment: In `*randomNum(array,9)` you dereference a void pointer and thus "get a void", which doesn't even make sense.

Comment: made a some edit to the question. hopefully it become clear to you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a perfectly fine generic function this way, but:

```
    result = array[rand()%(length-1)];
```

This is dereferencing the void pointer `array` while also attempting to store it into a pointer `result`. What you want to store is the address at that offset:

```
    result = array + rand()%(length-1);
```

However, you can't perform arithmetic like this on void pointers either, as the size of the underlying type is not known (some compilers allow `sizeof(void)==1` as an extension). With a non-void array, the number of bytes a given element consumes, and thus the number of bytes to increment by when doing arithmetic on the address, is encoded in the type. In a generic function operating on void pointers like this one you'll need to explicitly pass the size of the type.

```
void *randomNum(void * array, size_t size, size_t length)
```

Now perform the calculation by casting `array` to a char pointer, which forces arithmetic on `array` to occur in increments of 1 byte times the provided size parameter:

```
    result = (char*)array + (rand()%(length-1)) * size;
                   ^                            ^
```

You can then call randomNum with `randomNum(array, sizeof(*array), 9)`

However, you still need to cast the return value of the function before dereferencing it.

```
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)randomNum(array,sizeof(*array),9));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with the approach:

1) Since the argument `array` is of type `void *`, your plan of indexing it based on `length` will not work—for indexing to work, the length of each element in your array needs to be known as well. You seem to be trying to make a generic function that would work for any type of array, but honestly it's simpler to make a separate function for different types of arrays.

(To see why this is problematic, remember that `array[index]` is equivalent to `*(array + index)`; by indexing the `void *` you are applying pointer arithmetic to and then dereferencing the *void pointer*. Meditate on this.)

2) You are dereferencing a void pointer when you do `*randomNum(array, 9)`. This cannot be done; you need to cast the pointer to an appropriate type first, i.e., `*((int *)randomNum(array, 9))`, but as I said above, the whole approach with `randomNum` dealing in void pointers is problematic, so just change the whole thing to:

```
int *randomNumInt(int *array, size_t length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (well, the one causing the error) is: `*randomNum(array,9)`

Remember that the return type of randomNum is `void *`, which you dereference. The expression is therefore void. That does not make much sense to the compiler, and it issues an error.

Now, I am not quite sure *why* you declared `randomNum` to return `void*`, you might instead just have declared it `int`. You effectively convert an array value to a `void *`, which would point somewhere to the beginning og memory - an invalid location. If you were to cast the pointer to `int*`, your program would segfault.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference a `void` pointer like `*randomNum(array,9)` in your program. You should have to cast it before doing anything with `void` pointer.